# Show different set of fields in access report by criteria

Tags: database, ms-access, report

I have a table with a bunch of parameters for each unique tag, it looks something like this:

```
|Tag|Block Type|Alarm High|Velocity|etc|etc|
```

I need to create a report detailing these parameters of each block. Unfortunately, which parameters are not null depends on the block type. Consequently, is it possible to show certain fields, and not others, depending on value in the Block Type field of each record?

If so, can you please point me in the right direction.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you want visibility toggling on report columns. I don't believe you can build expressions for a text field's visibility property so you would need to show/hide the field in a report event handler, maybe "On Load". You could then write `If <BlockType condition> Then FieldName.Visible = True Else ... End If`. Other quick and dirty option would be using conditional formatting to change the color of the field background and text e.g. change it all to white. One issue you may have with either of the above is collapsing columns so you don't have empty whitespace.

Comment: I've tried this and faced the problem that the Visibility field is set globally, not by each record

Comment: So it's not simple column or row hiding; you want to show/hide specific cells in the column and row? If possible, could you include an example in your question please.

Comment: Yeah, because in some records they have an Alarm Value, in others they don't for example

Comment: Doing some research for you; currently blanking (changing field/text color) out the cell using conditional formatting is an interim solution. Depending on how you have laid out the fields on the report and what you expect the report to look like after visibility toggling.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that's all I've been able to find too